# Is it dangerous to have sentient combat computers on your ships?

Tags: stellaris

I know that sentient AI technologies are considered dangerous because they may lead to a revolution of sentient machines, but is this true of sentient combat computers? Will ships equipped with them defect in the event of an AI uprising or perform any other actions detrimental to my empire?

Comment: As far as I know ships cannot be infected, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I mean, what could go wrong? ;)

Comment: I haven't had any problems, but I've only had them for maybe 10 years, and AI already have full citizens' rights in my empire.

Comment: Do you want homicidal AIs? Because that's how you get homicidal AIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ships with Sentient AI will not join the AI Rebellion if it happens in your game.

Comment: With the Sythentic Dawn DLC, there is at least one drawback for sentient AI equipped ships.

Answer (score 4):

Included in the Synthetic Dawn DLC, The Ghost Signal during the Contingency crisis event will affect ships equipped with sentient AI combat computers.

The Ghost Signal has five levels of strength, corresponding with how many sterilization hubs that have yet to be destroyed. For every level of strength the Ghost Signal has, which starts at 5, ships will receive a 10% penalty to fire rate and tracking.

https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Crisis#The_Ghost_Signal

So no, it's not dangerous per se, but there are certainly still drawbacks that you will want to mitigate.